# How to get status of jira in velocity?

Tags: apache, jira, velocity, jira-plugin, polarion

Currently am using this code
    #set($Jira = $hi.getJiraStatus())
    $Jira\
 But am unable to get the status
Can anyone help me to get the status of jira in velocity script?

Comment: can you debug and cross check `$hi,getJiraStatus()` has the value?

Comment: The way you are calling it may be wrong mostly `$issue.getStatusObject().getName()` is used to get the status . Try and let me know

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still am not getting anything.

Comment: Its very hard to answer with the minimal input .Need more information by this i can't sorted out your issue? .

Comment: `$issue.status` try print this and check

Comment: check this link : https://valiantys.atlassian.net/wiki/display/NFEED55X/Velocity+variables